# Accessing Windows7_OS partition from Linux on a dual-boot

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, ntfs

Are there any limitations on accessing the Windows7_OS partition while I am booted on my Linux OS? Occasionally I like to browse files that are on my Windows partition or copy files to my Linux drive without having to reboot. This appears safe, but is there any risk with doing such operations? Sometimes I get Ubuntu internal errors, and I don't know if this may contribute to the cause.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) on a W520 ThinkPad 7200 RPM 500 GB HDD. I have a typical partition pattern: `SYSTEM_DRV` | `WINDOWS7_OS` | `UBUNTU_13.10` | `SWAP SPACE (7-8 GB)` | `LENOVO RECOVERY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you steer clear of Windows "system files" you should be safe enough.

If you're worried about endangering your Windows installation and only need read access to your Windows partition from Ubuntu, you can always mount the Windows partition read-only.

As `root`, open the file `/etc/fstab` and look for the line responsible for mounting your Windows partition. You want to edit the fourth field (mount options). This will probably have the value `defaults`. Simply change it to `defaults,ro`, where `ro` means "read-only".

The above will take effect at next reboot. To make it take effect in your current session as well, you can do this:

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro /path/to/windows
```

**See also**

- [Fstab HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) from the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki
- [fstab(5) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/fstab.5.html)
- [mount(8) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/mount.8.html)